# c++ to c# for statement

Tags: c#, c++

```
unsigned long uds_calc_key(unsigned long seed)
{
    unsigned long temp;
    unsigned short int  index;
    unsigned short int  mult1;
    unsigned short int  mult2;

    if(seed == 0)
    {
        seed = NC_DEFAULT_SEED;
    }
    else
    {}

    for (index=0x5D39, temp=0x80000000; temp; temp>>=1)
    {
        if (temp & seed)
        {
            index = croshortright(index, 1);
            if (temp & NC_UDS_KEYMASK)
            {
                index ^= 0x74c9;
            }
        }
    }

    mult1 = (nc_uds_keymul[(index>>2) & ((1<<5)-1)]^index);
    mult2 = (nc_uds_keymul[(index>>8) & ((1<<5)-1)]^index);
    temp = (((unsigned long)mult1)<<16)|((unsigned long)mult2);
    temp = mulu32(seed,temp);
    return temp;
}
```

I don't understand how to convert that temp value in the for statement. 
I am defining the temp value as an `uint`, and I got an error like  :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'bool';
```

I understand the fact that in C++ a zero is `false`, and anything not zero is `true`.
But here that is not applying as far as I see. Can you give me a hint about it ?

Comment: When you supply an error message, you **must** specify which line the error occurred on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
for (index=0x5D39, temp=0x80000000; temp != 0; temp>>=1)
```

and

```
if ((temp & seed) != 0)
```

and

```
if ((temp & NC_UDS_KEYMASK) != 0)
```

The two if are checking if the `temp` variable has a flag (`seed` or `NC_UDS_KEYMASK`).

Answer (score 7):

In C++ integers can be used in `if` statements. In C# you can only use expressions that evaluate to `bool`. Your expression `temp & seed` does not evaluate to a boolean. You should change the condition in C# to:

```
if(0 != (temp & seed)) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

C# does not convert anything to `bool` implicitly. Create the bool yourself: `myInt != 0`.

C# does it that way to avoid common coding mistakes at the cost of being slightly more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is here:

```
if (temp & seed)
```

`temp` is not of type `boolean`

You will either have to change the expression to `if (temp != 0)` or create another variable of type `bool`:

For instance `bool isTemp;`

And check that in the conditional.

```
 if (isTemp) { }
```

Comment: the error is also in the `for` loop itself, using `temp` as the condition. Replace with `temp != 0`. There is no need to create a boolean variable.

Comment: The problem is not that `temp` is not a `boolean`, the problem is that `temp & seed` is not a `boolean`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18357686/1711796) has the right idea.

Comment: @Dukeling - you can use `&` as a boolean operator, it will just shortcircuit.

Comment: @DarrenDavies No, `&` is not a boolean operator, it's a bitwise operator. `2 & 4` evaluates to 0.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I hope you mean it **won't** short-circuit (`&&` short-circuits, `&` doesn't).

Comment: @hvn - you can still use if (true & false) { } - it's perfectly legal.  See my MSDN link

Comment: From MSDN: `&` is Integer bitwise AND, Boolean logical AND

Comment: @DarrenDavies The documentation states `&&` has `bool` operands. That means, when `a` and `b` are integer types, `a && b` functions as `(bool)a && (bool)b`. *Then* your link says that *that* is the same thing as `(bool)a & (bool)b`. Yes, that's correct, but that has nothing to do with the question.